# spring integration - SFTP make sure upload is successfully

Tags: spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

How can we make sure whether the file is successfully uploaded to SFTP server. I want to make sure that SFTP upload is successful then only I want apply other logics. Here is my code to upload.

```
 @Bean
 public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() throws IOException {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost(config.getSftpHost());
    factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(config.getSftpPort()));
    factory.setUser(config.getSftpUser());
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    factory.setTimeout(10000);
    factory.setPrivateKey(new ClassPathResource(config.getPrivateKey()));
   } 
@Bean
   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
   public SftpMessageHandler uploadHandler() throws IOException {
    SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(config.getSftpRemoteDirectory()));
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
       if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
           return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
        }
      }
    });
   return handler;
  }
 @MessagingGateway
   public interface UploadGateway {
   @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    void upload(File file);
   }
```

I see the logs are looking good. Verified that files are getting uploaded to SFTP server. But somehow I am not able to make sure that files are getting uploaded on server. Please advise how to add code to make sure files are uploaded successfully.

```
  jsch Connecting to info.xyz.com port 22
  jsch Connection established
  jsch Remote version string: SSH-.0-Internal_SFTP__100
  jsch Local version string: SSH-.0-JSCH-0.1.4
  jsch CheckCiphers: aes6-ctr,aes19-ctr,aes18-ctr,aes6-cbc,aes19-cbc,aes18-cbc,des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour18,arcfour6
  jsch CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha-nistp6,ecdh-sha-nistp84,ecdh-sha-nistp1
  jsch CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha-nistp6,ecdsa-sha-nistp84,ecdsa-sha-nistp1
  jsch SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  jsch SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
  jsch kex: server: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha6,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  jsch kex: server: ssh-rsa
  jsch kex: server: aes18-ctr,aes6-cbc,aes19-cbc,aes18-cbc,aes6-ctr,aes19-ctr,des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour,arcfour18,arcfour6
  jsch kex: server: aes18-ctr,aes6-cbc,aes19-cbc,aes18-cbc,aes6-ctr,aes19-ctr,des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour,arcfour18,arcfour6
  jsch kex: server: hmac-sha-6,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha-1,hmac-md,hmac-sha-1-96,hmac-sha-6-96,hmac-md-96,hmac-sha6,hmac-sha6@ssh.com
  jsch kex: server: hmac-sha6,hmac-sha-6,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha-1,hmac-md,hmac-sha-1-96,hmac-sha-6-96,hmac-md-96,hmac-sha6@ssh.com
  jsch kex: server: none
  jsch kex: server: none
  jsch kex: server: 
  jsch kex: server: 
  jsch kex: client: ecdh-sha-nistp6,ecdh-sha-nistp84,ecdh-sha-nistp1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha6,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
  jsch kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha-nistp6,ecdsa-sha-nistp84,ecdsa-sha-nistp1
  jsch kex: client: aes18-ctr,aes18-cbc,des-ctr,des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes19- 
 ctr,aes19-cbc,aes6-ctr,aes6-cbc
  jsch kex: client: aes18-ctr,aes18-cbc,des-ctr,des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes19- 
   ctr,aes19-cbc,aes6-ctr,aes6-cbc
  jsch kex: client: hmac-md,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha-6,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md-96
  jsch kex: client: hmac-md,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha-6,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md-96
  jsch kex: client: none
  jsch kex: client: none
  jsch kex: client: 
  jsch kex: client: 
  jsch kex: server->client aes1-ctr hmac-md none
  jsch kex: client->server aes1-ctr hmac-md none
  jsch SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
  jsch expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
  jsch ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
  jsch Host 'info.xyz.com' is known and matches the RSA host key
  jsch SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  jsch SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  jsch SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
  jsch SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  jsch Authentications that can continue: publickeykeyboard-interactivepassword
  jsch Next authentication method: publickey
  jsch Authentication succeeded (publickey).
  jsch Disconnecting from info.xyz.com port 22
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean; if the upload fails, an exception will be thrown.

You can add a retry advice to the `SftpMessageHandler` to retry.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: I mean once file is uploaded to remote server how can we make sure it transferred to remote(SFTP) server successfully

Comment: If no exception is thrown, it was successful. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gary suggestion on adding retry advice to retry. I am getting below exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'toSftpChannel' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.getRequestChannel(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:387)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:422)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:568)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:489)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:464)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:453)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.upload(Unknown Source)
```

And my sftp Config looks below

```
    @Bean
    public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() throws IOException {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        //session config here, port, host, private key
      
  }
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel", adviceChain="retryAdvice")
    public SftpMessageHandler uploadHandler() throws IOException {
        final SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(config.getSftpRemoteDirectory()));
        //handler.setChmod(0600);   

        handler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {
            @Override
            public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
                if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
                    logger.info("Files request payload : " + message.getPayload().toString());
                    return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
                }
            }
        });

        return handler;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface UploadGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
        void upload(File file);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy(){
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
        return retryPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy(){
        FixedBackOffPolicy p = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        p.setBackOffPeriod(1000);
        return p;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice(SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy, 
     FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy){
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
        retryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        return retryAdvice;
    }
```